# Filtering query on Nginx

Tags: nginx, query

Can I store a specific query in `access_log` file by filtering with an expression?
For example I want to deny storing queries related to www.mydomaine.com and then reject it ?

Best regards,

Nizar.

Comment: rephrase your question

Answer (score 1):

You can set `access_log off;` inside a `location`. It will override the `access_log` setting at a higher level, and stop logging for any requests that match that `location`.

Comment: Hello, I'm newer in nginx. Have you a specefic example ?

Comment: For example, i want nginx to write requests on access.log only that dont contain **"mysting"**

Comment: Like this ? `server{ access_log off; location { if ($request != myString)access_log on;  }}`

Comment: @N.Khalifa That's valid syntax, but it would log to a file named "on", which is probably not what you want to name your access log.

Comment: Thak you :) In my example i invert it to server{ access_log on; location { if ($request != myString)access_log off; }}